# Dynamic Salience in Drools Decision Table

Tags: drools

How can I have dynamic salience in Drools decision table?
Suppose, If i want to assign salience value from a fact,how can i achieve it.
jBoss document says drools support dynamic salience but there is no specific example available for decision table.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: The purpose of a decision table is to select one case out of many, and the constraints should take care of that. So why would you need salience for a decision table in the first place?

Comment: In my case single fact can match multiple rule within an Activation group.So salience will decide which rule to will be executed.

Comment: Then it isn't a decision table in the strict sense of the world. Consider using templates which will give you plenty of leeway for using all DRL features.